# JavaScript: Detect whitespace and count character length

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to create an HTML text area input with some rules:

1. If the length of the character text input is 6, it will automatically create a new line (new line from character number 7).
2. But if those first 6 characters contain a whitespace, the new line should be started from the character after the whitespace.

Example: "run faster" - the new line should be from 'f' - faster and not 's' - ster

I successed to create the first rule with this code:

```
$("#txtInputCustom").on('change keydown paste input', function() {
     var a = this.value.replace(/(.{6})/g, "$1\n");
}
```

But I am struggling to reach my second rule.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("txtInputCustom").value.replace(/ /g, "\r\n").replace(/(.{6})/g, "$1\n");
```

Comment: but i need to make sure every line only has 6 character length (include whitespace).

Comment: I thought you are only searching a solution for the second problem? Why don't you just combine the two rules? You can, for example, check the length of the String. If it's less then 7, use my code, if it's bigger then 7, use your code.

Comment: I modified your answer to : var a = document.getElementById("txtInputCustom").value.replace(/ /g, "\r\n").replace(/(.{6})/g, "$1\n");

Comment: I just edited, thanks! And glad you found a solution!